# JSLINK from c# doesn't work

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to apply some custom render client (csr) to site column in XsltListViewWebPart with c# 
this is the code :

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sharepoint"))
        {                               
            site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            SPField Status = web.Fields["Status"];

            Status.JSLink = "~site/_catalogs/masterpage/CustomField.js";
            Status.Update(true);
        }
```

I get this error `Updates are currently disallowed on GET requests.  To allow updates on a GET, set the 'AllowUnsafeUpdates' property on SPWeb.`

`SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` doesn’t work either.

When I just add list view through the browser the CSR work perfectly but when I try to add list view through c#, the CSR doesn't work.

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: I find this link which explain a similar problem, [AllowUnsafeUpdates][1]

Anyway, I have done that trough visual studio when I define the site column. 

I think also this tutorial can help to use csr to custumize site column [csr tutorial][2]


  [1]: http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2011/03/sharepoint-updates-are-currently-disallowed-on-get-requests/
  [2]: http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this link which explain a similar problem, [AllowUnsafeUpdates](http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2011/03/sharepoint-updates-are-currently-disallowed-on-get-requests/)

Anyway, I have done that trough visual studio when I define the site column, I have add a csr file in layouts folder and apply through myview.jslink ="/_Layouts/15/csr/custom_field.js";

I think also this tutorial can help to use csr to custumize site column [csr tutorial](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013)

1. we can't apply xslt file and csr file on the same view. so I have removed the xslt file and combine javascript for the csr and css for the layouts.
2. When you use xsltlistview from webpart (c#) you have to save the javascript file in the folder layouts. and the link for this file has to be /_Layouts/15/folder/myfile.js

I hope this is can help.